# Error "mysql could not fetch schema table status"

Tags: mysql, host

The error **mysql could not fetch schema table status** occurs when I try backup or list  database tables using MySql Administrator.

I did some research on MySql Bugs (id=28140) and also MySql Forums (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,169966,170024#msg-170024). Their solution talks about McFee.

Actually I rent a Windows 2003 VPS host and I don't have any anti-virus installed. Do you know exactly what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql bug 28140 has two solutions, actually; one of them deals with McAffee, but the other says that it can occur if your TEMP or TMP environment variables point to a non-existent directory, or one that mysql does not have access to write to. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks Todd, 
I tried a non-existent directory such as c:\Temp\mysql2 and the server couldn't be started.
I denied permission for SYSTEm on c:\Temp\mysql and the server couldn't be started.

Comment: My host provider did install McAfee on the hardware node. It caused the problem and I'm asking them to make an exception scan on the folder c:\Temp\mysql. Thanks anyway!